# getting python module complete version with pkg_resources

Tags: python, distutils, python-module

I made a python package using distutils that in its setup.py file, has:

```
setup(name = "foo",
      version = "0.2.1",
      ...)
```

when I do:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("foo").version
```

I get `0.2` and not `0.2.1`. Why is that? how can i get the full version? thank you.

Comment: Can you post more code? Eg. is there anywhere you've specified '0.2'? I've checked the python packages docs (http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#distribution-attributes) and your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

pkg_resources looks for installed distributions in your Python installation.  Have you re-ran `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` after you’ve changed the version?

Try inspected the object returned by `get_distribution` for an attribute showing where the location is located on the file system; maybe foo is not installed where you think it is, and an older version is found instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug to me. If the package was installed with distutils instead of setuptools, then pkg_resources.get_distribution() returns the oldest version installed.

The best way to fix it is to replace:

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with:

```
from setuptools import setup
```